# Can I change server authentication to mixed mode in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, moss

I want to know weather I can used mixed mode authentication on sql server instance being used for SharePoint2010 installation; without breaking the licence terms for SP2010.

Comment: To What SQL are you talking about, did you use the one sharepoint installs on his own? or is it another sql?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I have created a custom database in the sql-instance used/created by SharePoint. Now I want to use mixed-mode authentication for this custom database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of licensing so I can't answer your question officially.

But I know now that Sharepoint 2010 uses SQL Express 2008 R2 (not that different windows database) that does have database limit of 10 gb however blobs are now stored with filestream that changes the storage game.

in Summary: I Believe you can change the auth to mixed mode, however you will not be able to connect through it remotelly due to a sql express restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Word document [here](http://fbasp.codeplex.com/) for details on how to configure mixed authentication.

Comment: his question is about whether he can or can't enable mixed mode due to licensing, not about how to do it, nor how to make sharepoint use it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that exposing custom SharePoint 2010 SQL database with mixed-mode authentication violates the MS license agreement, although I am not 100% sure about that and you can ask them directly. Not sure about the restriction Gabriel mentioned, I am not familiar with that.